# WinHTTP and Windows 7 x64: Error

Tags: windows-7-x64, winhttp

I have an application which uses WinHTTP, and it seems under Windows 7 (64-bit; have yet to test the 32-bit version) the call to WinHttpOpen fails, returning

> "The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation."

This corresponds to error code 5023, and occurs for the Administrator as well as a standard user. The C++ DLL containing this call was compiled using Visual Studio 2008 (32-bit) on a Windows XP Professional system.

Other than Outlook 2007, this is an otherwise clean install in a VM.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running with elevated privileges as well as an administrative account? I believe that the HTTP daemon requires elevated privileges to execute.

Comment: I must admit I haven't the foggiest on that one. I just tested the DLL from a C++ command line test program with the same result (this is normally called from a C# user control). I'm a total neophyte in the Windows 7 area, so I sort of suspect it's a permissions issue of some kind.

Comment: Installation on Vista (32-bit) does not result in the same behavior. Interesting...

Answer (score 1):

It appears to have been a timing issue. I was calling WinHttpOpen in the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH section of DllMain. Moving it from there seems to have resolved the issue.